# How can I set the chapter-counter to infinity?

Tags: chapters, counters, number

My professor introduced us to infinite graph-theory and made a little gimmick: Instead of increasing the chapter number by one, he set it right to infinity. Now I want to get it into my LaTeX-Documents as well. Has anyone an idea how to do it?

Currently its 2866, since thats what LaTeX gives you, when you use \setcounter{chapter}{\infty}.

Comment: In TeX you can't set a counter to infinity. What you could do instead is make the instruction that actually prints out the page number insert the `\infty` symbol: `\renewcommand\thepage{$\infty$}`

Comment: Or `\thechapter`.

Comment: Ohhh, why did I type `\thepage`? Brains are strange. Thanks @JohnKormylo

Comment: Thank you! But is there any way to get the functionality of \chapter{} back when making a chapter 9 after chapter infinity?